# Overwrite local branch with remote tracking branch (branches have diverged)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I have create a new branch named *my-4.3.y* using the following command
(note: *my-4.3.y* is set up to track remote branch *4.3.y* from origin):

```
git checkout -b my-4.3.y origin/4.3.y
```

I haven't worked on the *my-4.3.y* branch after checking it out.
Now, several days later, when I run:

```
git status
```

It tells me that *my-4.3.y* and *origin/4.3.y* have **diverged**.

I don't care where and why the branches have diverged, I don't want to merge
the remote branch into my. I just want my branch to be equal to the remote
branch again.

So, what I am doing is: (1) checkout some other branch (2) delete *my-4.3.y* and (3) check it out again:

```
git checkout some_other_branch
git branch -D my-4.3.y
git checkout -b my-4.3.y origin/4.3.y
```

Is there an easier way to that?

Comment: use `git reset --hard origin/4.3.y` instead

Comment: @AndrewC That's what I was looking for. Would you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git reset --hard` to force your currently checked out branch to any arbitrary point you would like.

Note: using `--hard` is not working directory safe, and will throw out any changes you have.

For the specific case of updating to your tracking branch you can use `@{u}` to specify your upstream

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

Generally, you can pass in any branch reference or anything else Git resolves to a commit e.g.

```
git reset --hard origin/4.3.y
```